# Can I define relations without explicit transformation rules?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, attributes

Is there an alternative way to use *Mathematica* for symbolic algebra, where instead of defining explicit transformation rules into 'canonical form', I can instead 'gently inform' Mathematica about certain relations, and let it take care of the rest? For example, the `Orderless` attribute achieves this when the relation in question is total symmetry of a function in its arguments.

I've been using Mathematica to do symbolic manipulations in non-commutative algebra. There's been a persistent barrier to doing this effectively, which is that I can't just define relations between objects in *Mathematica*-- it seems that I need to define *transormation rules*.

Here's an example. I'm using `NonCommutativeMultiply`. I'm defining a commutation relation between two objects. I have `NCMPower` which is the same as the `Power` function really, but it corresponds to `NonCommutativeMultiply` instead of `Times`. I want the following commutation relation:

```
Dc[mu_]**R - R**Dc[mu_] := Partial[mu, R];
```

Of course, the above won't work, and in *Mathematica* I'm forced to choose a sort of `normal form' to put everything in. So I would need to make the following definition, for example:

```
Dc[mu_]**R := Partial[mu, R] + R**Dc[mu];
```

That's okay for this example, but this gets quite tedious for larger examples, and also it requires me to figure out a canonical norm form in which everything would eliminate in the way that I want. It gets worse: I need this to work correctly with `NCMPower` too. So I need to make multiple definitions like this:

```
Dc[mu_]**R := Partial[mu, R] + R**Dc[mu];
NCMPower[Dc[mu_],n_Integer]**R/;(n>0) := NCMPower[Dc[mu],n-1]**(Partial[mu, R] + R**Dc[mu]);
Dc[mu_]**NCMPower[R,n_Integer]/;(n>0) := (Partial[mu, R] + R**Dc[mu])**NCMPower[R,n-1];
NCMPower[Dc[mu_],m_Integer]**NCMPower[R,n_Integer]/;And[m>0,n>0] := NCMPower[Dc[mu],m-1]**(Partial[mu, R] + R**Dc[mu])**NCMPower[R,n-1];
```

This is getting really verbose and time-consuming for something so simple. But, even worse, I actually have to tell *Mathematica* explicitly *how* to manipulate symbols. I don't particularly care about the form in which an answer is presented-- until or unless I request it to be simplified.

Another example is to specify that tensors have certain symmetries-- for example, the Riemann and Ricci tensors in General Relativity. I would like to specify these symmetries and then have Mathematica *automatically take account of those symmetries without requiring explicit normal forms*, similar to the way that one can use `SetAttribute[f, Orderless]` to make Mathematica magically take care of simplifications when the object is totally symmetric.

I stress that this is a broad problem I have in general with Mathematica over a period of time, rather than a specific example; it just seems that the usual approach of explicit transformation rules (which requires a specification of a 'canonical' form when there may be no natural choice) is not suited to abstract algebra. **What I'm looking for is a way to *inform Mathematica* about relations between symbols, and to specify an objective function that measures complexity, and have Mathematica try all possible transformations to achieve that lowest complexity.** That is, I'm basically looking to make my own version of `Simplify` with an objective function like `LeafCount`. (Of course, with the least effort possible!)

So, could someone please let me know how this is done in Mathematica, or otherwise reccommend a programming language which is more suited to this type of task? I know that Maple is capable of defining algebras with certain commutation relations, for example. Thank you.

P.S. I have heard of the `NCAlgebra` package which I will look into later. But I am looking for a general approach which I can use for a variety of algebras.

Comment: Have you looked at the `TransformationFunctions` option to `Simplify`?

Comment: @LukasLang nope, never heard of it. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look.

Comment: @LukasLang - I should add that I'm also looking for an option that Mathematica also uses in its pattern matching. I.e. if I say that `A` is equivalent to `B`, then I want Mathematica to match against `B` wherever I put `A`. It sounds trivial, but again, it's one of those things that blows up in complexity when defining a bunch of symbols and relations. I don't want to write boilerplate every time!

Comment: This might get long and philosophical: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144634/room-for-lericr-and-myridium